# Add custom action on records in the list view/related list drop down list

Tags: related-list, quickaction

Is it possible to add an action on this section?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add custom action on the related list.  However, you can use a custom button on the related list.

Review below Idea link

[Add quick actions on related lists](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2)

Comment: Thanks Vinay for your answer. Can i add a custom button that invokes a lightning component?

Comment: Yes,  here is an example (https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/16/add-lightning-component-lightning-action/)   Thanks